# Ubuntu : loss of sound

Tags: ubuntu

I suddenly lost sound in my computer. Sound card is recognized but no sound output

[image]

Comment: l can't make the output volume up !!! it's a gray area

Comment: Is there by any chance a keyboard button for turning sound off?

Comment: yes f10 . l tried that but the problem remains

Comment: Restart the comptuer. If the problem remains, write down all the things you tried so far and then it will be easier to help!

Comment: l did that also. then l wen to terminal l removed and installed again my sound card, updated all sound packages but the problem still remains

Comment: And the mute button above the volume scale, in the fading window up in the right corner of your image. I'm on XFCE right now, but as i remember you can press it to toggle mute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42847/discussion-between-sam-tzaurtis-and-jonatan-ostrom).